# How to disable Service provider initialized SSO in Spring SAML?

Tags: java, spring, saml, spring-saml

My product uses only Identity Provider initialized SSO and it works fine.
Requests to http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO are validated. For correct requests a session is created, for wrong ones I am getting status 401.

I have problem with incoming requests to other endpoints (ones that should be secured), like 
http://localhost:8080/messages

When request has correct, authenticated session id  it works fine.
But for not authenticated requests, I am redirected to my Identity provider page, with URL

https:///sso/SSO?SAMLRequest=

How to disable that behavior? I want just to reject those requests with 'Authentication failed' response, without any interaction with Identity provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `SAMLEntryPoint` which is responsible for initialization of SP SSO. Spring Security will then use the default entry point which should behave as you expect. You will still be able to send SAML messages to /saml/SSO.

**Edit:**
Detailed steps are given below

1. Create bean implementing *org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint*
   Simplest imlementation is  `<bean name="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>`
2. Use that bean in `<security:http entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">`
3. Remove  `<bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfecty! I edited your answer and added detailed steps.